# RTL8723DE : "no wifi adapter found" on kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, realtek

I have currently installed kali  (dual boot windows 10) ,but when i ran kali linux os it shows no wifi adapter found.

Comment: After lspci command it shows ..03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter

Comment: "_I have currently installed kali [...] I am completely new to linux_". Don't try to learn using Kali. Take one of the beginner-friendly distributions instead - you can still install all of Kali's tools on it but you won't keep getting burned by strangenesses.

Comment: Also see [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Should I Use Kali Linux?](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) in the Kali docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE3: Alternative solution based on HP website manual:

```
    sudo apt update && sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
    cd Downloads
    git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
    cd rtlwifi_new
    make 
    sudo make install
    sudo dkms add ../rtlwifi_new
    sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6 
    sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
    sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6 --force
    sudo modprobe -v rtl8723de ant_sel=2
    sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf'
```

OLDER VERSION not worked for Kali Linux (real distro name: Debian Testing):

```
editor /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

Then you just need to run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install firmware-realtek
reboot #Obvious this will reboot your system.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84033/discussion-on-answer-by-luciano-andress-martini-kali-linux-no-wifi-adapter-foun).

Comment: For those that don't have an ethernet connection for their computer (some laptops), you can't update the system if you don't have WiFi in the first place.

Comment: You will need to have a alternative connection, cable connection, or to copy the firmware and drivers files to a pendrive. For the apt-get files, apt-get clean, them apt-get -d thefile in a machine with connection, the files will be in /var/cache/apt/archives and can be installed by dpkg. Another option is to download all the debian dvds with firmware, and enable it on the kali repository.